# How to simulate QR code scanner with Mac as an external keyboard?

Tags: ios, macos, bluetooth, qr-code

Is there a way to use Mac as an external bluetooth keyboard to simulate QR code scanner to send a string to iPhone device?

I've seen some paid Mac bluetooth keyboard simulator apps on the App Store and wonder if there some free utility that can just act as a bluetooth keyboard and send a simple string and Return key to iPhone over bluetooth.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the ShowQR utility for Mac that transforms any text selection to its QR equivalent; then there are many available App for any mobile device to scan the QR and copy the text in the clipboard or directly share the scan with other Apps such Mail,Whatsapp, etc. I do use this trip very often especially when sending URLs or sending long phrases from my mac to whatsapp conversation.
You can download the package from: http://ricsxn.github.io/ShowQR/